# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'int' and 'set'

Tags: python, typeerror, pow

**Question:**
Without using any string methods, try to print the following:
123...n
Note that "..." represents the consecutive values in between.

Example
n=5
Prints 12345.

**my solution**

```
n = int(input())
sum=0
i=n
while i>0:
    sum=sum + i*(10**{n-i})
    i -= 1
print(sum)
```

Comment: what did you mean by ```{n-i}``` in the code?

Comment: `{n-1}` is a set display; braces and parentheses are not interchangeable.

Comment: Also, take a look at [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner's_method) rather than repeatedly using the `**` operator.

Comment: yes i meant to raise the power. and I'm a beginner and this is the logic i could come up with so might not be fullproof. i solved the error by simply defining m as n-i and using that instead.

Comment: also the method fails if the value goes beyond 9. so for 10, next iteration would add 90 to it making it 100. so instead of getting 12345678910, we get 1234567900. any method based on addition would fail i guess. would be doable with strings but the question explicitly states not to use that:)

Comment: so what is the range of acceptable input? if the input is 12, should the output be ```123456789101112``` or should it errors? if the input is -5, should the output be ```-54321``` or should it errors?

Answer (score 1):

First: `{n-i}` will evaluate to `{-1}` if n=0 since `{x}` is way to express a [set](https://realpython.com/python-sets/) in python

Second: you're asking for method to print numeric string, but no string operation (so all concatenation should be done in addition between two integers). Here I'm assuming that the accepted input can only be positive number

e.g.:

- input 5, output=12345
- input 12, output=123456789101112

When learning to solve such 'challenge' problem, it's better to do it test driven: write a simple program that just work, then compare/assert with generated expected result

this is the correct but not acceptable way to generate the output (with string operation):

```
inp = int(input())

expected = ""
for i in range(1, inp+1):
  expected = expected + str(i)

print(expected)
```

Then try to solve it gradually: assume single digit input only. Here we got the idea that in order to place a number beside other number, we need to multiply first number by 10, then next number by 1. So your solution for making it multiplied by power of ten is already on correct track

now we can write:

```
inp = int(input())
result = 0
for i in range(1, inp+1):
  power_of_ten = 10**(inp-i)
  print("pot", power_of_ten)
  result = result + (i*power_of_ten)
  print("r", result)
print(result)
```

output:

```
5
pot 10000
r 10000
pot 1000
r 12000
pot 100
r 12300
pot 10
r 12340
pot 1
r 12345
12345
```

at this point, we can try to assert if our output is the same with our generated output (the one that use string operation):

```
inp = int(input())
result = 0
for i in range(1, inp+1):
  power_of_ten = 10**(inp-i)
  result = result + (i*power_of_ten)
print(result)

expected = ""
for i in range(1, inp+1):
  expected = expected + str(i)
print(expected)
assert(result == int(expected))
print("assertion passed")
```

output:

```
5
12345
12345
assertion passed
```

but if we use two digit input, the output will no longer be correct:

```
12
123456790122
123456789101112
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/c.py", line 14, in <module>
    assert(result == int(expected))
AssertionError
```

so, if we have to output 123456789101112 when we input 12, then we need a mathematical function (not a string function) that can count the number of digit in a number:

- output 2 if we input 12, 40, 99, 80 (two digit number)
- output 1 if we input 1, 5, 2 (one digit number)
- etc.

such function is called logarithm function: e.g.:

```
math.floor(math.log(i, 10)) + 1
```

first we try to logarithm the input to base 10, then we floor the result (so that the result is not a decimal/fractional number); then we add 1

here is the code that incorporate that: note that for simplicity, we're looping backward (e.g.: 12,11,10,9..1)

```
import math
inp = int(input())
result = 0
pad = 0
for i in range(inp, 0, -1):
  result = result + i*10**pad
  pad = pad + math.floor(math.log(i, 10)) + 1
print(result)

expected = ""
for i in range(1, inp+1):
  expected = expected + str(i)
print(expected)
assert(result == int(expected))
print("assertion passed")
```

here I added a variable `pad` that will contain the number of pad to be added on next iteration, e.g.: input=5

- iteration=1 i=5 pad=1 result=5 (so next number, i.e: 4, will be multiplied with 10^1)
- iteration=2 i=4 pad=2 result=45 (so next number, i.e: 3, will be multiplied with 10^2)
- iteration=3 i=3 pad=3 result=345
- iteration=4 i=2 pad=4 result=2345
- iteration=5 i=1 pad=5 result=12345

when input=12

- iteration=1 i=12 pad=2 result=12
- iteration=2 i=11 pad=4 result=1112
- iteration=3 i=10 pad=6 result=101112
- iteration=4 i=9 pad=7 result=9101112
- iteration=5 i=8 pad=8 result=89101112
- iteration=6 i=7 pad=9 result=789101112
- iteration=7 i=6 pad=10 result=6789101112
- iteration=8 i=5 pad=11 result=56789101112
- iteration=9 i=4 pad=12 result=456789101112
- iteration=10 i=3 pad=13 result=3456789101112
- iteration=11 i=2 pad=14 result=23456789101112
- iteration=12 i=1 pad=15 result=123456789101112

output:

```
$ python3 /tmp/a.py 
5
12345
12345
assertion passed
$ python3 /tmp/a.py 
12
123456789101112
123456789101112
assertion passed
```

so the final code is:

```
import math
inp = int(input())
result = 0
pad = 0
for i in range(inp, 0, -1):
  result = result + i*10**pad
  pad = pad + math.floor(math.log(i, 10)) + 1
print(result)
```